# Getting error when creating Rails 3.2.16 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using this command to create my rails app (version 3.2.16)

```
rails 3.2.16 new myapp
```

but I am getting following error

```
/home/hardik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (= 3.2.16) - did find: [railties-4.0.0,railties-3.2.14,railties-3.2.13] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/hardik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /home/hardik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/hardik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: you may install rails version 3.2.16 first?

Comment: Nevermind `gem install rails -v 3.2.16` has done the trick and now I can create it. :|

Comment: @devanand thanx, about time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message

```
Could not find 'railties' (= 3.2.16) - did find: [railties-4.0.0,railties-3.2.14,railties-3.2.13]
```

You have not installed rails 3.2.16, but you have 4.0.0, 3.2.14 and 3.2.13

```
rails new myapp
```

should do it

If you need to specify the rails version, you should use [rvm](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)